# Rename [sdl-2] to [sdl2]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Everywhere when I look for information about SDL 2, I search for SDL2. [Official downloads](http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) are also labeled as `SDL2-2.0.1.zip`, not as `SDL-2.0.1.zip`. So I propose to rename `sdl-2` tag to `sdl2` to be consistent with `pysdl2`.

Comment: @BartoszKP, I believe `sdl-2` tag appeared after the rule about no hypenated aliases came into play, so I am afraid there will be no hits for `sdl2`to be considered worthy.

Comment: @BartoszKP, no problem. Happens every time. =)